# How to print the heatmap in a square shape using seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

When I run the code below I notice that the heatmap does not have a square shape knowing that I have used `square=True` but it did not work! Any idea how can I print the heatmap in a square format? Thank you!

The code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import os
import seaborn as sns

temp_hourly_A5_A7_AX_ASHRAE=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\cvaa4\\Desktop\\projects\\s\\temp_hourly_A5_A7_AX_ASHRAE.csv',index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, skiprows=2)
sns.heatmap(temp_hourly_A5_A7_AX_ASHRAE,cmap="YlGnBu", vmin=18, vmax=27, square=True, cbar=False, linewidth=0.0001);
```

The result:

[image: heatmap result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use matplotlib and set a figsize before plotting heatmap.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rnd = np.random.default_rng(12345)
data = rnd.uniform(-100, 100, [100, 50])

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
sns.heatmap(data, cmap='viridis');
```

[image: heatmap seaborn]

Note that I used `figsize=(6, 5)` rather than a square `figsize=(5, 5)`. This is because on a given figsize, seaborn also puts the colorbar, which might cause the heatmap to be squished a bit. You might want to change those figsizes too depending on what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to read a file using a=pd.read_csv  instead of using a random function but it gave me this error: DataFrame' object has no attribute 'uniform' any idea how to read it and then use figsize?

Comment: just plot your dataframe `a` directly. I simply used numpy's uniform to generate random data.

Comment: It gave the same result :(, am I missing anything in the code:
a=pd.read_csv('salam.csv',index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, skiprows=2)

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 6))
sns.heatmap(a, cmap='viridis');

Comment: Youre doing it right yes. can you post a sample of your csv file?

Comment: Sure, check the file using this link: http://www.filedropper.com/salam

Comment: `a = pd.read_csv('salam.csv') plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
sns.heatmap(a.set_index('Timestamp'), cmap='viridis')` works for me. https://imgur.com/T7aY7YF

Comment: It is still rectangular in shape, I want the cell size to be square not rectangular. I think it is something to do with xticklable and y ticklabel but don't know yet how to use them.

Answer (score 3):

`square=True` should work to have square **cells**, below is a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.tile([0,1], 15*15).reshape(-1,15))

sns.heatmap(df, square=True)
```

[image: square cells]

If you want a square shape of the **plot** however, you can use `set_aspect` and the shape of the data:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
ax.set_aspect(df.shape[1]/df.shape[0]) # here 0.5 Y/X ratio
```

[image: square plot]

Comment: It reduced the shape itself but not the size of the cell which still in a rectangle form, check the file using this link and let me know if it works with you please:  filedropper.com/salam

Comment: So which of the two outputs would you like? Square cells or square plot?

Comment: square cells, as the cells are still in a rectangular shape